# Unable to add Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS to PCL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to workout a [**sample project using MvvmCross**](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc---The-Core-Project), but I'm stuck with the first step of adding the frameworks in VS2012.

[image]

When I try to add `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.iOS` framework in a `PCL` project, it is showing an error

> There is no available functionality that is portable between the
>   frameworks you have selected

I tried following the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15091234/1671639), but it didn't worked.

Can someone shed some light on this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you change *Silverlight* to version 5 and *Windows Phone* to version 8? Do you still see the error?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson great! it is working.  Thanks.  but what happens for lower versio frameworks?

Comment: I think that the combination you selected just isn't supported by any PCL profile, probably because there is not enough overlapping functionality. Alternatively, I think you can "downgrade" .NET Framework to version 4, but I don't think a PCL with that profile could consume the *MVVMCross* assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent (mainly good) changes from Microsoft mean that the platforms that can officially be used together is now set to:

- sl5
- wp8
- winstore
- wpf with .net 45
- the xam twins

To support these try the 3.1.1 release from Mvvmcross - currently available in beta as Try the beta packages - 3.1.1-beta5 - use "include prerelease" in nuget.

Comment: I think you're pointing [`MvvmCross 3.1.1-beta1`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross/3.1.1-beta1).  When I tried in nuget console, it is suffering error.  please correct me if this is wrong

Comment: Actually I feel the problem with .net framework 4.5, as mentioned in this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571543/unable-to-add-xamarin-android-and-xamarin-ios-to-pcl#comment32585161_21571543) I changed it and this solved my problem.  Thanks for your help :)