# How to correct reference Xamarin PCL class?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Visual Studio 2017, a fresh new Xamarin solution is created with Portable Class Library.
[image]

A initial build shows success. But a run gives an error message:
[image]

warnings like

> Unable to add a reference to project 'App1'. The current project's target is not one of or compatible with the targets of Portable Library project 'App1'.

It is in both App1.iOS and App1.Android.
[image]

I have not yet upgrade the Xamarin NuGet package yet. The UWP project can run without any warning or exception.

Look into the project reference on the Android project, we see the broken reference to App1.
[image]

Trying to reference that PCL project again, I got

[image]

Look into the Property of the App1 PCL project,

[image]

What could be wrong? How can I fix the PCL project so it can be correctly referenced by Android and iOS projects?

Comment: Is your PCL a .NET Standard?

Comment: I am afraid not. It is created by the "Cross Platform App (Xamarin)" template.

Comment: Perhaps, you can try to use .NET Standard: https://oren.codes/2016/07/09/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard/

Comment: If you don't wanna change the Target Platform, you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15091234/5056173